# Python Regex, Finding what is in between two substrings

Tags: python, regex, string

The regex I have right now is:

```
string="hello (fdd()()()()(()(())()))"
re.match("%s\s*\((.*?)\)$"%re.escape("hello"), string)
```

And it will work well, the goal of it is to get whatever is inside the brackets.
In this case: `"fdd()()()()(()(())())"`

I would like to make an alteration, the regex should work with this test case

`"hello (hihihi(((())))hihi)  {  "`

There is a curly-brace at the end of it. There should always be a curly-brace at the end of the given string therefore the first test case that I showed you will not work anymore (with the new regex that I want).

Try looking at it like this

`hello[any amount of space]([get WHATEVER is inside here])[any amount of space]{[any amount of space]`

I think that using the dollar sign is what is causing me problems. I am obviously not too familiar with using regex, so if anyone can help me that would be great. I am open to any solution including but not limited to other python modules, built in python string features, ect.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: HINT: If you think the `$` is causing you problems, have you tried removing the `$` (and the `?`)?

Comment: also remove `?` otherwise it ends at the nearest `)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just use `"hello\s*\((.+)\)\s*{"`

```
import re

text = "hello (hihihi(((())))hihi) { "
print re.match(r'hello\s*\((.+)\)\s*{', text).group(1)
```

gives me

```
hihihi(((())))hihi
```

You don't need the `?` and `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your regex to the following:

```
r"%s\s*\((.*?)\)\s*{" % re.escape("hello")
```

The only difference here is that the `$` was replaced by `\s*{`, which means any amount of whitespace followed by a `{`.

Example:

```
>>> s = "hello (hihihi(((())))hihi) { "
>>> print re.match(r"%s\s*\((.*?)\)\s*{" % re.escape("hello"), s).group(1)
hihihi(((())))hihi
```